# Populate an input text with the incoming URL parameter with MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a link in one view that when i clicked it goes to another view passing an id parameter into the URL like this:

```
<a href=Gestion/ImagenesPublicacion?id=2 class="alert-link">Publicar imagen</a>
```

That URL is calling this method action of the controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ImagenesPublicacion(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This action method it is rendering the HTML of this view that has an input text that i want to populate with the id parameter:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <p><strong>Nº Expediente:</strong></p>
    <input class="form-control" id="ExpedienteNro" name="ExpedienteNro" type="number" placeholder="Nº Expediente" required autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Any possible ideas of how can i do this?

Comment: Pass the `id` value as a Model to the View and insert it in to the output

Comment: Pass a model to the view containing a property `int Id` and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)` to generate the control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following method

```
 [Authorize]
public ActionResult ImagenesPublicacion(int id)
{
   ViewBag.Id = id.ToString();
   return View();
}
```

and inside your view change the **value** attribute

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<p><strong>Nº Expediente:</strong></p>
<input class="form-control" id="ExpedienteNro" name="ExpedienteNro" type="number" placeholder="Nº Expediente" value="@ViewBag.Id" required autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure you only need the one value, you can set it as entire model.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

and the view

```
@model int

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <p><strong>Nº Expediente:</strong></p>
    @Html.TextBox("NoExpediente", Model, new { @class = "form-control",
        @type = "number", placeholder = "Nº Expediente", 
        autocomplete = "off" })    
</div>
```

Although as the comments suggest you may well prefer to use a model. In particular if you want to post the page back to the server, you stand a much greater risk of typos compared to the strongly typed `@Html.TextBoxFor()` method or just populating the value from the ViewBag.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me alot! I'll use a model then because i want to pass more values.

Comment: One more thing, when i want to send that value into a form is sending null into the controller of the form that i'm using like this way public ActionResult ConfirmarPublicacion(FormCollection frm){
int ExpedienteNro = int.Parse(Request.Form["ExpedienteNro"])};  The Request.Form["ExpedienteNro"] is null now. Do you know how can i resolve that?